# How to reconnect mongoose to another remote server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am totally new to node.js and mongoose, how to reconnect mongoose to another remote server ?
At the beginning of the file I have

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

and connected to localhost,

later in code I have

```
var uristring ='mongodb://remote_server/db';
var mongoOptions = { db: { safe: true } };

// Connect to Database
mongoose.createConnection(uristring, mongoOptions, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log ('ERROR connecting to: remote' + uristring + '. ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log ('Successfully connected to: remote' + uristring);
    }
});
```

and I always get `Successfully connected to: remote` but when I bellow that print look for document by id I get always from local database(I have schema imported like `require Person = mongoose.model('Person');`).
How to reconnect to remote if I already have connection to local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of initializate a connection in `mongoose`:

1. Using the default connection "object"
2. Creating a connection from the dust

Here you are creating a connection, but using a model from another. Models are tied to databases (normal databases, replica sets or clusters) so you're not accesing to the correct host.

You must use the default connection (using `mongoose.connect` instead of `mongoose.createConnection`) or create a model in that new connection you are using. In your example:

```
  var uristring ='mongodb://remote_server/db';
  var mongoOptions = { db: { safe: true } };

  // Connect to Database
  var newConnection = mongoose.createConnection(uristring, mongoOptions);

  newConnection.model(/*whatever*/);
```

`mongoose.model` wires to `mongoose.connection`. That is not the new connection you have created.